# Error connecting mysql database with php Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter and I can't connect my database, give me an error:
[image: Error connecting database]

I just add the library  in autoload.php :

```
`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`
```

and this are my settings in database.php

```
    $active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'database' => 'heroes',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

:S any help?

Comment: What library did you add? What are your settings inside application/config/database.php? Please give some more details.

Comment: I've just updated it

Comment: Did you make any modifications to index.php , maybe wrong system path? Does the application work without database lib?

Comment: yes without the library it works

Comment: try to change hostname 127.0.0.1 instead localhost and check wheter port 3306 is blocked (default mysql port)

Comment: not work, the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88629/discussion-between-cssblaster21895-and-ali-atriple).

Answer (score 1):

Just I changed localhost by `127.0.0.1:3306`

Comment: But this is the answer ... :S